# What a web link does? What verb to use?

Tags: grammar, verbs

The sentence: "The 'Contact us' link in the navigation bar ... to an error page" (When you click it you get an error page)

Does it directs to / points to / refers to /  leads to / ... may be there is more. Which to use? And also can I say 'A link opens an error page' ?. 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Web links LINK.
According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:
link 
transitive verb
: to couple or connect by or as if by a link.

Answer (score 0):

The technical term would be **link** for most cases

> (transitive verb)
> : to couple or connect by or as if by a link
>
> (intransitive verb)
> : to become connected by or as if by a link —often used with up
>
> (from [Marriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/link))

but in this case, since the link points to a non-existent page, you can use the technical term **redirect**

> To send to a new location by substituting an address or pointer. (from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/redirect))

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, a link *points to* a target. However, in the case of a broken link, it may *redirect to* an error page. *Redirection* describes the action taken by the server when one resource is requested but a different resource is returned; i.e. an error page in place of the 'Contact us' page.

> The 'Contact us' link in the navigation bar ***points to an invalid location***.
>   The 'Contact us' link in the navigation bar ***redirects to an error page***.

Unless, of course, the link itself *literally points to* the error page. In this case, you would say **points to** instead of **redirects to**.

```
<a href="/404">Contact us</a>
```

When describing the issue you are facing, however, it will be clearer to reference the specific error. There are many error pages that can be presented for many different reasons.

> The 'Contact us' link in the navigation bar ***404s***.
>   The 'Contact us' link in the navigation bar ***redirects to a 'Page Not Found' error page***.